# how to change the trunk name of cocoapods after pod trunk register?

Tags: cocoapods, trunk

When I use cocoapods trunk register, I used a random name, but now I want make it more readable. But there is no way to change it...
Event I use "pod trunk register email 'new name'" again. it doesn't works. :(

Answer (score 13):

In terminal

```
grep -A2 'trunk.cocoapods.org' ~/.netrc
```

'Password' in response is your TOKEN. Copy it to clipboard. Then replace parameters in the following line and run it:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Token <MY CURRENT TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"<MY EMAIL>","name":"<MY NEW NAME>","description":"<My DESCRIPTION>"}' https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/sessions
```

You will receive an e-mail. Follow the link in it.

DONE!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too.

Comment: Legendary. Worked great for me

Comment: nice+++++++++++++